# How to append file name in the row it belongs to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application you can access [here][1]. When you open up the application, you will see an "Add" button on top, click this twice and you will see 2 table rows appear with each row containing it's own file input.

The problem is:  suppose you try to upload a file (a small file for quick upload) in the second row's file input. After you have uploaded a file, the name of the file which has been uploaded is appended into both the top row and the second row. This is incorrect, it should only append the file name in the second row only because you used the second row's file input to upload that file.

How can I append the file name within the same row as the file input used to upload the file?

Below is the code for the form which contains the file input:

```
 function insertQuestion(form) {  

  var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
  var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
  var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>"); 

    var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
    "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "<label><input type='button' name='imageClear' class='imageClear' value='Clear File'/></label>" +
    "</p><ul class='listImage' align='left'></ul>" +
    "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");

    $image.append($fileImage);

    $tr.append($image);  
    $tbody.append($tr);

    };
```

Below is the handler the form directs to when clicked:

```
 function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
      if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
          return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
      } 
      return false;
  }
```

Below is where the file uploading starts and stops:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');

      return true;
}


    function htmlEncode(value) { return $('<div/>').text(value).html(); }


    function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

          var result = '';

          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
              $('.listImage').append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
          }

  $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

    $(this).parent().remove();

});

    return true;

    }
```

CORRECT SOLUTION:

```
     function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
          if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
 window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); 
              return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
          } 
          return false;
      }

         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button><br/><hr/></div>');
```

Comment: Why did you delete your [previous question (10k only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390262/how-to-append-file-name-in-its-correct-row)?

Comment: I wanted to re-ask the question in a lot better way. So I thought it would be better if I deleted the previous question and ask it again but iin a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is:

> $('.listImage')

That is a selector for "any element with the class 'listImage'".  Since you've clicked add twice, there are two elements with this class, and your selector matches (and appends) to both of them.

Use a more specific selector for your append and you should be all set.

Unfortunately, I can't recommend a specific way of doing that, because I don't know how your `stopImageUpload` function is being called. If it's being triggered by a jQuery event handler, then you can refer to "this" inside your function to get the element that triggered the event, and you should be able to use that to figure out which .listImage to append to.

If it's not triggered by an event handler, then I would imagine that whatever function is calling it knows which file input triggered things.

Once you know which element you actually want to append to, you can target it using jQuery's eq method/selector.  Here are a couple examples:

```
$('.listImage:eq(0)') // selects the first listImage only
$('.listImage').eq(2) // selects the third listImage only
```

Comment: Hopefully all of the above makes sense, but if not feel free to post back and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I tried using $( this ).closest but this hasn't worked. I will post whole code show how everytihng is triggered and how the code flows so you understand. Give me 10 mins :)

Comment: I have updated question so it includes whole code so you can see the flow and see how everything works :) I know it is a lot of code but it should be easy to follow hopefully.

Comment: So you didn't mention the key part: how stopImageUpload is triggered ... but fortunately I was able to figure it out by looking at your linked site.  It turns out it's being triggered from the onload code of the window inside the hidden iframe (the iframe that's the target of your image upload).  This complicates things a bit, because that window has no idea which file input triggered it.

So, what that means is that you need to start tracking things earlier.  This could get more complex than I can explain in a SO comment, but the basic idea is that you need to do something like

Comment: (inside imageClickHandler) window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform);  Then (inside stopImageUpload) change your $('.listImage') to $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).  Now this is a simplistic solution, which won't work well if the user tries to upload two images in rapid succession ... but A) that isn't likely to happen, and B) hopefully this at least gives you the basic idea.

Comment: I will give this ago, if you can provide me a sample code of what you are saying then this is great but at the mean time I will try and implement what you have told me to do :)

Comment: Sorry no example code; if I was independently wealthy I could take the time to write out example code, but since I'm not the best I can do is explain things/answer questions/point you in the right direction.  Good luck :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, it did work, I just put the `window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); ` in the wrong place in the function. Anyway best answer and correct solution been posted in bottom of the question :) Thanks